# ASP.net DataList doesn't show any thing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datalist

I have DataList1 in my page . I want to fill Datalist by a command . But with this codes Datalist doesn't show any things. but when I use gridview , the Gridview showes 4 rows:

```
        db = new da();
        dt = new DataTable();
        string sql = "SELECT TOP (4) id, titr, sum  FROM newstxt ORDER BY views desc";
        dt = db.select(sql);

        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

da is a class for doing sql commands.

Comment: A class for doing sqlcommand based on 3 layered

Comment: did you add columns to datalist appropriately, since gridview autogenerates but data list does not.

Comment: Datalist hasn't columns property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should specify the item template in the datalist markup, for example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Container.DataItem("id")%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

check this article for an example: [DataList Example in ASP.NET using C#](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/datalist.html)